# Visual studio prompts 'Save as...' dialog on an already saved file.

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. I've created a new ASP.NET Web application project and added a new web page to it using the 'Web Form with Master Page' template.

This is how the folder structure of my project looks like:

[image]

The web page I mentioned above is 'DempoReport.aspx'. I now open the page make a few modifications to it and click on the 'Save' button.

Quite unexpectedly the 'Save As..' dialog open up:

[image]

This shouldn't happen as the file has already been saved many times before. If I click on 'Save', then, of course, I get the message:

> The process cannot access the file 'c:\Users\Giorgos\Web
>   Reports\WebForms\DemoReport.aspx' because it is being used by another
>   process.

Does anyone have any idea about what could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: check with processexplorer from MS as to what has the file open.

Comment: Please delete .suo and try

Comment: Did you try closing Visual Studio and opening it again...?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, sometime it works, sometime it doesn't!

Comment: So check using ProcMon/Process Explorer/Unlocker who is locking the file. Perhaps a virus scanner or Visual Studio itself.

Comment: @BugFinder Yes, this is a good tip. I think it is the google drive synchronization process. I'm using a google drive folder to save my project.

Comment: @BugFinder Post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whats opening the files using the processexplorer from Microsoft, that way you can track down whats causing it.  What to do post that is dependent of course on whats opening the file.

Comment: This tip saved my day! It was the 'Backup and Sync' from Google. I had to disconnect in order to unlock the file.

Comment: Technically it then falls outside SO.. as it becomes a standard PC question.. but glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Had no success with processexplorer, I found the solution in Microsoft forums,

Google Backup and Sync was blocking the files, closing it resolved the issue immediately.

So check if the file is Synced by Google Backup and Sync or similar programs

I even can see the google drive folder in @Giorgos Betsos pictures :)

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Check my comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: yeah, :)
I missed your comment, could have saved so much time